# Chrome css print styles leaves text overlapping

Tags: html, css, printing, cross-browser

We have been working on a new calendar interface which includes a printable "classic" calendar view. There was much working going into the `@media print stylesheet`, and while everything is looking great in `Safari`, the event times are overlapping the event name in `Chrome`. Cannot figure out why.

```
@media print {
    body{
      -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
    }
    img,
    .calendar-nav button,
    .calendar-date-picker,
    .event .btn-group {
        display: none;
    }
    .calendar-nav {
        text-align: center;
        padding-top:20px;
    }
    .calendar-nav .date-title {
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    a:link:after,
    a:visited:after {
        content: "";
    }
    #calendarTable div.event {
        padding: 0;
        margin-left:0; 
        text-indent: 0;
    }
    .events.active {
        width: 100%
    }

}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** I fixed the overlap issue by adding `.event-location {float: none; margin-top: 0px;}` into the print media query.

Also, in `Firefox` there is a huge margin to the left of the content:

[image]

It is pretty hard debugging these print style sheet to figure out what is going on. Even `Chrome` developer tools will show the correct print preview, but doing a real print shows it incorrect.

Any ideas on what to do to fix these issues? Is using an `@media print` inside of our main style sheet an issue?

**http://www.puc.edu/calendar?state=full**

Comment: Could provide a demo showing this problems? It's pretty hard to say without some html and css.

Comment: Sorry about that, I had meant to. Just added the URL and the `@media print` styles.

Comment: I have not printed this yet. But you can reproduce the above screenshot, when you make your browser window very small. You seem to have some floating problems caused by `@media (max-width: 767px)
.event-location {`. Maybe you can [exclude the responsive media queries from printing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#not) for a start.

Comment: @NicoO - I was able to fix the overlap issue, and updated my question. But Firefox still is an issue with a huge left margin. Will look into the other media query.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like adding a few styles to overwrite the `Bootstrap` defaults was all I needed:

```
.event-location {
    float: none !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
}
.event-time {
    float: none !important; 
}
body .container {
    width:100% !important;
    margin:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: For what its worth, I came here via Google and this got me closer with some similar issues. My client wanted the print style to be 2 column, and I used CSS columns to accomplish it, but print does NOT like 2 columns. It resulted in lots of text overlapping. Lesson: Avoid using `column-count` in your `@print` media stylesheet.